# How to tell Eclipse what file to run in a PHP project?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I am on `Eclipse Luna (4.4.0)` on Ubuntu.

I have some files in my PHP project. For example, I have 2 files in my project: `index.php` and `solve.php`, I am editing `solve.php` and I press F11. Eclipse will run `solve.php` but I want it to run `index.php` anyway.

What should I do to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you just need to create a Debug Configuration for the project with your main php file as the main file of the project . Take a look at [this step by step tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/debugging_a_php_web_page.htm) to configure it the right way .

[image: Debug conf]

Take look at the [Debugging using XDebug](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug) documentation for more information .

Comment: It seems that I'll have to make a debug configuration for each file. It doesn't seem to be the best way. And anyway, I could make a run configuration for each file.